# query the GA custom dimension from google big database

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I would like to select the custom dimension from google big.

However, I do not understand why has the  error

```
SELECT MAX(IF(index=1, value, NULL)) FROM UNNEST(hits.customDimensions) AS dimension1

FROM 'atomic-life-148403.131256355.ga_sessions_*',  UNNEST(hits) as hits
```

error is :
Error: Syntax error: Unexpected keyword FROM at [3:1]

Answer (score 1):

Each `UNNEST` operation you apply corresponds to a [cross-join](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays#flattening-arrays) operation on the data. You can therefore flatten your arrays like so:

```
SELECT
  MAX(IF(index=1, value, NULL))
FROM 'atomic-life-148403.131256355.ga_sessions_*',
UNNEST(hits) as hits,
UNNEST(hits.customDimensions) AS dimension1
```